# Index is outside the bounds of the array VB 2015

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting this error message, and it points to this line

> Index was outside the bounds of the array
>
> bookinfo(i).Author = parts(1)

Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
   Private Sub JamesProject1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    MyBase.Load
    Dim parts() As String
    lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("LibraryDatabase.txt")


    ReDim Preserve bookinfo(lines.Count)

    If Not OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        MessageBox.Show("You must choose a file")
        Me.Close()
    End If

    lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)


    For i = 0 To lines.Count - 1
        parts = lines(i).Split(","c)
        bookinfo(i).Title = parts(0)
        bookinfo(i).Author = parts(1)
        bookinfo(i).ISBN = parts(2)
        bookinfo(i).YearPublished = parts(3)
    Next

    Dim query = From book In bookinfo
                Order By book.Title, book.Author, book.ISBN, book.YearPublished
                Select book.Title, book.Author, book.ISBN, book.YearPublished

    DGVBookInfo.DataSource = query.ToList

    DGVBookInfo.Columns("Title").HeaderText = "Title"
    DGVBookInfo.Columns("Author").HeaderText = "Author"
    DGVBookInfo.Columns("ISBN").HeaderText = "ISBN"
    DGVBookInfo.Columns("Year Published").HeaderText = "Year Published"
    DGVBookInfo.AutoResizeColumns()


    DGVBookInfo.RowHeadersVisible = False



End Sub
```

Comment: You have two `lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(...` statements, but only `Redim` `bookinfo` after the first occurrence.  What you you think happens if the second file has more lines than the first.

Comment: Clearly the `parts` array has only one element. That means `lines(i)` must not contain a comma. Possible the file contains a blank line,

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not debugging your code. You generally don't diagnose issues simply by reading code. You need to run it and watch it in action, setting breakpoints in appropriate places, stepping through the code and examining the state. If you don't know how to debug, you should start learning [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). So many issues become easy to solve when you debug because you see what actually is instead of what you assume will be.

Comment: You know that you need four items in `parts` so after `parts = lines(i).Split(","c)` put `If parts.Count <> 4 Then Throw New Exception("Error at file line " & (i + 1))` and it will tell you which line has the faulty data.